# Java JCA - Input length must be multiple of 8 for padded decypher

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I'm currently doing an assignment for a college course using Java's JCA.
The application takes in a file and encrypts it (or decrypts it) using DES-ECB. **I am fully aware that it's not a secure encryption algorithm.**

It encrypts fine, I believe, however when decrypting it blows up with a "Input length must be multiple of 8" even though the original message is being padded with PKCS5.

I have read all literature and quetions regarding this problem here on StackOverflow, but none of the answers seem to resolve this issue, which leads me to believe I am somehow corrupting the message/file...

For the encryption:

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, symmetricKey);

    
    File file = new File(filePath);
    
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("encrypted_"+file.getName());

    
    CipherInputStream cipherStream = new CipherInputStream( new FileInputStream(file), cipher);


    byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER]; //buffer para leitura
    int bytes; //bytes a ler

    //Encoder base64 - Apache Commons Codec
    Base64 encoder = new Base64();

    
    while ( (bytes = cipherStream.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
        
        byte[] encodedBuffer = encoder.encode(buffer);
        
        outputStream.write(encodedBuffer, 0, bytes);
    }

    
    cipherStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();

    return outputStream;
```

For the decryption:

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, symmetricKey);

    
    File file = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream cipheredStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("decrypted_"+file.getName());

    
    CipherOutputStream cipherOutStream = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, cipher);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER];
    int bytes;

    //Decoder base 64 - Apache Commons Codec
    Base64 decoder = new Base64();

    cipheredStream.read(buffer);
    byte[] decodedBuffer = decoder.decode(buffer);
    byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(decodedBuffer);
    cipherOutStream.write(output);

    //TODO bug here -> use this for big files
    /*while ( (bytes = cipheredStream.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
        byte[] decodedBuffer = decoder.decode(buffer);
        cipherOutStream.write(decodedBuffer, 0, bytes);
    }*/

    cipherOutStream.close();
    cipheredStream.close();

    return outputStream;
```

I've tried using AES to no avail; I've tried no padding, obviously it didn't work.

I'm just lost and would appreciate knowing what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: During decryption, the buffer is filled only once. As with encryption, a while loop should be used so that the entire ciphertext is decrypted. This is already implemented in the code but commented out, why? Also, the Base64 encoding during encryption should be removed, as it is not necessary (and is also implemented incorrectly). Similarly, the Base64 decoding  during decryption is to be removed.

Comment: I commented out the loop because it generates the same type of error. Since I'm only trying with small files at the moment, I just took that part out. As for base64: I do want to use Base64 encoding, though. Could you expand on how I'm using it incorrectly and how I would go at it?

Comment: The buffer size for encryption and decryption must be compatible (because Base64 generates 4 output bytes from every 3 input bytes). This is complicated by the fact that `read()` does not _necessarily_ fill the buffer _completely_, so `readNBytes()` simplifies the implementation. The easiest way is to use `Base64InputStream` or `Base64OutputStream` of [`org.apache.commons.codec.binary`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/package-summary.html) that encapsulates these details.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Topaco, the solution was found using Base64InputStream.

Because the deciphering was being done BEFORE decoding, it was generating that error. It was fixed by doing this encryption side:

```
        Base64OutputStream encoder = new Base64OutputStream(outputStream);

        
        while ( (nBytes = cipherStream.read(buffer, 0, MAX_BUFFER)) != -1 )
            encoder.write(buffer, 0, nBytes);
```

And decryption side the exact opposite:

```
Base64InputStream decoder = new Base64InputStream(fileInputStream);


while ( (nBytes = decoder.read(buffer, 0, MAX_BUFFER)) != -1 )
    cipherOutStream.write(buffer, 0, nBytes);
```